# Doctrine 2 EM -> getting the result from 1 table with 2 entities

Tags: entity-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have 2 entities in Doctrine: User and Club. Both are containing this text in the entitie:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="sms_followers")
 **/
private $smsfollowers;
```

The other target entity is Club.

I use findOneBy() to retrieve the club for a overview. You can see all the data that is for the club.

Now i wanne show how many SMS followers there are. How am i supposed to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This should get you up and running. I put all the code in the controller to makes it easy for you to understand.

```
 <?php

 namespace Acme\YourBundle\Controller;

 use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAware;

 class YourBundle extends ContainerAware

    /**
     * @return EntityManager
     */
    protected function getEntityManager()
    {
        return $this->container
            ->get('doctrine')
            ->getEntityManager();
    }

    /**
     * Get the number of followers for a particular class
     *
     * @param string The class 
     * @return int The number of followers
     */
    protected function getNumberOfSMSFollowers($class)
    { 
        $entityManager = $this->container
            ->get('doctrine')
            ->getEntityManager();

        $queryBuilder = $entityManager
            ->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('count(f.id)')
        //  from the appropriate class
            ->from($class, 'c')
            ->innerJoin('c.smsfollowers','f');

        return $queryBuilder
            ->getQuery()
            ->getSingleScalarResult();
    }

     /**
     * Get the number of followers in 2 different entities
     *
     * @return response The response you wish to give
     */
    public function getNumberOfFollowersAction()
    {
        // Your classes
        $userClass ="Acme\UserBundle\User";
        $clubClass ="Acme\ClubBundle\Club";

        $nbFollowersInUserClass = $this->getNumberOfSMSFollowers($userClass);
        echo $nbFollowersInUserClass;

        $nbFollowersInClubClass = $this->getNumberOfSMSFollowers($userClass);
        echo $nbFollowersInClubClass;

       //...
    }
}
```